# Detect hotkeys from fullscreen game

Tags: vb.net

I've made an overlay extension for a fullscreen game. I want to activate different commands using hotkeys while in the game. I used to use `GetAsyncKeyState` and then use a timer to constantly check if the `KeyState` has changed. I then switched to using a `RegisterHotKey` function like the one shown below:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Public Const MOD_ALT As Integer = &H1 'Alt key
    Public Const MOD_CONTROL As Integer = &H2 'CTRL key
    Public Const MOD_SHIFT As Integer = &H4 'Shift key
    Public Const MOD_NOREPEAT As Integer = &H4000 'NoRepeat
    Public Const MOD_WIN As Integer = &H8 'Windows key
    Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312

    <DllImport("User32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("User32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1, MOD_CONTROL + MOD_ALT + MOD_NOREPEAT, Keys.D)
        RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 2, MOD_ALT, Keys.C)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
            Dim id As IntPtr = m.WParam
            Select Case (id.ToString)
                Case "1"
                    MessageBox.Show("You pressed CTRL+ALT+D key combination")
                Case "2"
                    MessageBox.Show("You pressed ALT+C key combination")
            End Select
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 1)
        UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 2)
    End Sub

End Class
```

This works perfect, and I'm able to use the noRepeat to only fire the function once even if i hold down the hotkeys, which is something i struggled with while using the `GetAsyncKeyState` and a timer. My problem is that the form wont registrer the keys being pressed when I'm inside the game. When I'm in any other program which isnt running in fullscreen it detects the hotkeys just fine. Should i go back to the `GetAsyncKeyState` or is there another way of detecting hotkeys even when inside a full screen game?

Comment: Perhaps this MSDN post will help, as mentioned hooks are the solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/221e7216-1bc2-480a-b9ec-68e7f556c03e/visual-basic-hotkeys-in-full-screen-applicationsgames?forum=winforms

Comment: Good luck on hooks, the  game cheat scanner will pick this up... It watches certain function calls: SetWindowsHookEx, CallNextHookEx, UnhookWindowsHookEx and GetModuleHandle.

Comment: @zaggler : What game cheat scanner? Steam's? I believe applications capturing mouse/keyboard still works in that case. Also why would hooks be considered cheating? :)